# Horizontal responsive div without using display flex

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align 2 horizontal divs which will be responsive as well. But for some reason the second div is falling after the first one.

I used `display: flex;` to the div `#content-twinwidth-container`. It worked but I would like to do it without using display flex.

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
}

#content-twinwidth-container {
  max-width: 1002px;
  width: 100%;
}

#content-twinwidth-container #sidebar1 {
  background: #323537 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 0;
  max-width: 245px;
  padding: 18px 15px 28px;
  width: 100%;
}

#content-twinwidth-container #sidebar1 h2 {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0 0 1rem;
}

#content-home h2 {
  background: #ff2bff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-bottom: 0.2rem;
  padding: 12px 0 10px 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

#content-twinwidth-container #sidebar1-right {
  background: #ddd none repeat scroll 0 0;
  clear: none;
  float: left;
  max-width: 740px;
  padding: 0 0 0 1.2rem;
  width: 100%;
}

#sidebar1-right h1 {
  clear: none !important;
  color: #80e2ee;
  display: block;
  float: none !important;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-style: normal;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 0 !important;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="content-twinwidth-container" class="clearfix">
  <!-- BOF SIDEBAR 1 -->
  <div id="sidebar1" class="clearfix">
    <h2>Summary</h2>
  </div>
  <!-- EOF SIDEBAR 1 -->

  <div id="sidebar1-right" class="clearfix">
    <h1>Client Area</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a layout problem that is easily solved with flexbox. It's likely one reason why flexbox was created. But if you want both divs to exist on the same line with floats, then you'll have to adjust their widths to divide the available space among them.

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
}
#content-twinwidth-container {
  max-width: 1002px;
  width: 100%;
}
#content-twinwidth-container #sidebar1 {
  background: #323537 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 0;
  /* max-width: 245px; */
  padding: 18px 15px 28px;
  width: 25%;
}
#content-twinwidth-container #sidebar1 h2 {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0 0 1rem;
}
#content-home h2 {
  background: #ff2bff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-bottom: 0.2rem;
  padding: 12px 0 10px 15px;
  width: 100%;
}
#content-twinwidth-container #sidebar1-right {
  background: #ddd none repeat scroll 0 0;
  clear: none;
  float: left;
  /* max-width: 740px; */
  padding: 0 0 0 1.2rem;
  width: 75%;
}
#sidebar1-right h1 {
  clear: none !important;
  color: #80e2ee;
  display: block;
  float: none !important;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-style: normal;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 0 !important;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="content-twinwidth-container" class="clearfix">
  <!-- BOF SIDEBAR 1 -->
  <div id="sidebar1" class="clearfix">
    <h2>Summary</h2>
  </div>
  <!-- EOF SIDEBAR 1 -->

  <div id="sidebar1-right" class="clearfix">
    <h1>Client Area</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Michael_B Actually I had 3 divs under the main div (#content-twinwidth-container) which was using flexbox. Now I wanted the 3rd div to be under 1st & 2nd but it was not possible so I had to leave the idea of using flexbox. I applied clear right to 2nd div so that the 3rd div comes under 1st but that was not happening. But this solution works great.

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra, Actually, it is possible with flexbox, and its simpler and more efficient than the float solution: https://jsfiddle.net/16j8mbnv/1/

Comment: That's brilliant. flex wrap is the key. I was looking exactly for this.